# Silent save without prompting in Revit API

Tags: c#, revit, revit-api

I'm using the Revit 2011 API and when I do `Document.Save()` on an existing family file it prompts me with the "Save As" dialog to specify a file name.  How can I have it save without prompting the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the family files were read-only.  By default Revit will save files silently but for some reason when they are read-only it doesn't throw an error but instead prompts for a save location.  I would have figured out the read-only part had I tried to actually save them but I think it would have made more sense for the Revit to throw an error on `Document.Save` than prompt for a new save location.